# How to get a notification when a form sheet (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) has disappeared?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a view controller (A) that presents another view controller (B) modally as a form sheet (UIModalPresentationFormSheet).

Now I want to dismiss view controller B, and present another as soon as it's safe to do so (because you can't use `presentModalViewController:` while another view controller is being shown or dismissed.)

However, I can't seem to find any way to be notified when the form sheet has fully disappeared. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is what we did.

Since the view controller controlling the form sheet (B) *does* get `-viewDidDisappear`, we just add the presenting view controller (A) as a delegate, which we then notify by hand when `-viewDidDisappear` gets called on the (B) view controller.

The delegate definition looks like this:

```
@protocol FormSheetViewControllerDelegate

- (void)formSheetViewDidDisappear;

@end
```

We add a delegate to the FormSheetViewController:

```
@interface FormSheetViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <FormSheetViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

And we call `-formSheetViewDidDisappear` from the FormSheetViewController:

```
@implementation FormSheetViewController

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [delegate formSheetViewDidDisappear];
}

@end
```

**P.S.:**
Since iOS 5 and blocks, UIViewController has the method

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

Which you could use to react to the dismissal of the form sheet view.

Answer (score 3):

As no doubt you have noticed, the old `viewDidAppear` methods are not fired when the `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` controller is dismissed. One can emulate the viewWillAppear call by simply calling that method when you dismiss the controller, but that isn't what you need.

Rather than presenting a second modal view controller, can you push your new viewController to the existing modal view controller's navigationController?  This may give a nicer user experience anyway.

Or can you use a popover?

Comment: Incidentally, for anyone who finds this needing a 'viewWillAppear' to be called, the pattern to do achieve is described here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/3/ipad-modal-view-controllers.html (under ModalViewControllerDelegate)